# Ограничить количество потоков

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, synchronized

Уважаемые знатоки!!
Есть необходимость ограничить количество потоков до одного.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    //ThreadLocal
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ids[i], buildUpdate(context, ids[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
super.onUpdate(ctxt, mgr, appWidgetIds)
```

Пробую вот так - не получается. Подскажите что к чему.

Comment: копни в сторону ExecutorService

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? В приведенном вами коде запускается ровно один поток.

Comment: В коде я показал пример, как я пытаюсь поставить в "очередь" потоки. Поток запускается виджетом через onUpdate. Просто если устройство выключено, то по включению запускается сразу несколько потоков подряд, а это приводит к нежелательным последствиям

Comment: так у вас андроид?

Comment: Да. Простите. Забыл метку поставить

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `ThreadPool`, в котором количество **потоков** будет ограничено до **1**.

В JDK есть уже готовые пулы потоков, подробнее можно почитать тут - [Executors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) (есть метод, возвращающий `ExecutorService` с одним рабочим потоком [newSingleThreadExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())).

Comment: Только в JDK, а не в Android SDK.